# How can I replace the search box into search icon?

Tags: catalogsearch

Can anyone explain how to replace the default search box into search icon?

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE! Which is your Magento version?

Answer (score 0):

You will **get search button** in

```
app/design/[Your_theme]/default/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml
```

You can change it to icon in many way using **css** or including **icon image**.